# Keeping unused column in Spark when using groupBy?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe of usernames that contains threads that they have posted and the timestamps of those posts. I am trying to figure out who was the first user who posted the thread and what time it was. I know how to figure out the first post is to apply `groupBy()` on a thread and then apply `min` on the timestamp. But that removes the usernames. How do I use the `groupBy()` while keeping the usernames?

Comment: Group by username

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one groupBy by using a HiveContext and the Hive named_struct function.  The trick is min will work on a struct by evaluating the columns in order from left to right, and only moving onto the next one if there the current column is equal.  So, in this case, it is really just comparing the timestamp column, but by making a struct that includes the name you will have access to that after the min function spits out the result.

```
data = [
    ('user', 'thread', 'ts'),
    ('ryan', 1, 1234),
    ('bob', 1, 2345),
    ('bob', 2, 1234),
    ('john', 2, 2223)
]

header = data[0]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data[1:])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, header)
df.registerTempTable('table')

sql = """
SELECT thread, min(named_struct('ts', ts, 'user', user)) as earliest
FROM table
GROUP BY thread
"""

grouped = sqlContext.sql(sql)
final = grouped.selectExpr('thread', 'earliest.user as user', 'earliest.ts as timestamp')
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the row_number() window function, this will keep all other columns intact.
Use withColumn to create a new column something like "thread_user_order" and its value should be **row_number() PARTITION BY thread ORDER BY ts**.
Then filter **"thread_user_order" == 1**.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
df.withColumn("thread_user_order", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(col("thread")).orderBy(col("ts")))).where(col("thread_user_order").equalTo(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the struct sorting order to sort fields by order and preserve two columns at once. Then when you call `min` it will sort by timestamp first and then username if/when two times tie.

```
user_time = functions.struct(df.timestamp, df.username).alias('user_time')
min_thread_users_df = df.select(df.thread, user_time).groupby('thread').agg(
    functions.min('user_time').alias('user_time')).select(
    'thread', 'user_time.username', 'user_time.timestamp')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply include username in the groupBy statement:

```
df = df.groupBy("thread", "username").agg(F.min("post_timestamp"))
```

If including `username` in the groupBy statement will cause an issue with the data (e.g. it is structured in such a way that this will not result in the correct value), then simply join it in after grouping, since this will be a simple one-to-many join.

```
df = df.groupBy("thread").agg(F.min("post_timestamp"))
username_df = df.select("thread", "username").distinct()
df = df.join(username_df, ["thread"], "left)
```